# Android permission checker syntax error

Tags: java, android

I was working on a call app and needed to request the `CALL_PHONE` permission and when i tried starting the call activity `startActivity(callIntent);` it gave an error and said i needed to set a permission checker and after i set one it gave me an error on the `this` statement saying that

`Wrong 1st Argument  type.Found:'android.view.View.OnClickListener',required:'android.context.Context'`

so heres my my main activity if you could pease help me rectify it

```
package com.android.beez.emergencyng;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button alert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alert);

        alert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

change `this` to `MainActivity.this`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing context reference of your click listener which is wrong. Use MainActivity.this as an argument

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

instead of

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your context refers to anonymous class that you created with `new View.OnClickListener`. To fix your error change `this` to `MainActivity.this`.